# For loop unexpected behavior

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.5

I'm a python beginner and I'm learning about the `for` loop. So please can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code because my program doesn't run (EVEN ON THE PYTHON SHELL)

```
words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
for w in words:
    if len(w) > 6:
        words.insert(0, w)
```

Comment: what error do you get ?

Comment: as far as I can tell there are two main problems. The indentation is incorrect and you are looping and modifying the list at the same time

Comment: For both problems that @mic4ael has mentioned, maybe the reason why it "doesn't work" is because it is still expecting another line. Press enter again, it will run and throw an error.

Comment: Please post code without the `>>>` Those are distracting. In any event, it isn't a good idea to write multi-line code in the shell. If you are a beginner, you are much better served by learning how to write script files ASAP.

Comment: If I'd ask you to count a bunch of oranges on the table and every time you are about to count the last one I'd add another orange, I can assure you that you will act oddly as well :).

Comment: While You are traversing through list, You should not alter the words list

Comment: @John Coleman, Thanks sir, i'll keep note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code seems to have 2 problems as commented by @[mic4ael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1527018/mic4ael):
The first is indentation, `words.insert` should be inside the `if` block, also, you're appending to the same list you're looping, which will cause an endless loop if there's a match.

The solution is to indent properly and create a new list to hold the matches, i.e.:

```
words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
wordsMatch = []
for w in words:
    if len(w) > 6:
        wordsMatch.insert(0, w)
print wordsMatch
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/374Qxb)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are creating an infinite loop. You iterate over that list and if you find a word which is longer than 6 characters you are adding it to the list.